# Spring MVC environment specific information on JSP

Tags: spring-mvc

What is the best of displaying environment specific information (Dev, QA etc.) on the view JSP in Spring? I am thinking of reading that information from a properties file. Whats the simplest way of making that properties file data available to the view JSP?

So far looks like I need to use JSTL to read the properties, but I don't want them localized!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Spring 3 themes for this and having a different property file for the themeResolver per environment.